# Are deep technical details on topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope

I posted a [GPS-Question](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/46486/31824) and got a very good answer to it.

But - I am interested in further technical details about this topic. The answer hints that "The details of that are well beyond the scope of this site" and linked to the developement site explaining the API.

I am rather a sysadmin than a developer, so that API gives me some clues but does not explain how this works on OS (i.e. Android) level in deeper detail (which is what I am interested in).

Are those questions like:

- What OS-process does what in Android?
- Is there a Android-standard-filesystem-layout?
- How does the boot-process in Android work in detail?

Still on topic here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, those questions aren't on-topic.  The reason is fairly straightforward — this site is for end-users.  Curiosity is a valid reason for asking a question, but at the end of the day we expect questions and answers to be applicable in some way to a problem faced by an end user.

The closest we get to your last question, for example, would be when an advanced user wants to have an extra script or app run on startup.  This would be a valid question for us, and the answer might involved a partial description of the boot process, but laying out the whole process in detail is going to be a lot of extraneous information that our audience simply cannot make use of.

Your questions *might* be on-topic on Stack Overflow but again, it would be best if you could connect them to a problem.  If you were creating your own ROM and modifying boot if not the source code then there would certainly be many reasons to ask those sorts of questions.

I think your GPS question is not the most solidly in-scope, but acceptable.  As an end user, you made an observation about something your phone was doing, which resulted in the question.